# Accessing a Label from a Textbox through AssociatedControlID

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I have a label and a textbox and a label

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Name" AssociatedControlID="txtName"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
```

From code-behind, is it posible to access the controls that list the Textbox as an associated control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, but probably not as easy as you'd like.  There is no collection anywhere that says "these are all the controls with this AssociatedControlID value".  You would need to [loop over all the controls in the page recursively](https://blog.codinghorror.com/recursive-pagefindcontrol/) and check the AssociatedControlID property if it's a label.

What are you trying to accomplish?  I know you specifically asked about doing it code-behind, but if the end result is that you're trying to manipulate the UI, I would consider using jQuery, as with a single line of javascript you would be able to select all the elements on the page that had `for = "txtName"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using LINQ.

```
var label = Page.Controls
                .Cast<Control>()
                .SingleOrDefault(c => c.GetType() == typeof(Label) &&
                                      ((Label)c).AssociatedControlID == "txtName");
```

If you have multiple controls associated with that particular textbox, then use `Where()` instead of `SingleOrDefault()`.